# Cannot cast to class imported on condition of TYPE_CHECKING

Tags: python, python-3.x, casting, mypy, python-3.10

### 1. Context

I often import python modules only for the type-checker, like `mypy`. For example:

```
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    import bar
```

I would then use module `bar` in type hints throughout the code. These type hints are only visible for type-checkers, while `bar` itself won't be imported when running the code live.

Giving type hints this way works just fine. However, when attempting to *cast* types, I get a 'module not found' error.

### 2. Example

Let's consider the following example. I have three modules/files:

- `test.py`
- `foo.py`
- `bar.py`

This is `test.py`:

```py
# FILE: TEST.PY
# =============
from typing import *
import foo
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    import bar

def my_func():
    foo_obj:foo.Foo = foo.Foo()
    bar_obj:bar.Bar = foo_obj.get_something()
```

The type-checker `mypy` complains about the last line. Now let us take a look at the function `get_something()` in `foo.py` to figure out why:

```py
# FILE: FOO.PY
# =============
import bar

class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        ...
        return

    def get_something(self) -> Union[bar.Bar, str]:
        ...
        return something
```

The type checker `mypy` knows that `get_something()` returns either a `Bar()`-object or a string. Therefore, `mypy` complains. Fair enough.

Now I know for a fact that - in this particular situation - `get_something()` *will* return a `Bar()`-object. The type checker mustn't worry. My first reflex therefore would be to give a hint to the type checker with an assertion or a cast:

```py
# ASSERTION:
# Give hint to type checker with an assertion
something = foo_obj.get_something()
assert isinstance(something, bar.Bar)
bar_obj:bar.Bar = something

# CAST:
# Give hint to type checker with a cast
bar_obj:bar.Bar = cast(foo_obj.get_something(), bar.Bar)
```

The cast approach looks the most elegant to me, because it can be done with minimal overhead. Also, the cast has no runtime effects. At runtime, the `cast()` function is essentially a `nop()`. Only type-checkers see the cast.

### 3. The problem

Unfortunately, the cast throws a 'module not found' error at runtime. That's not what I expected it to do. After all, at runtime casts should be totally ignored! I see a few ways to deal with this, but they all have their downsides:

- **Import module `bar` unconditionally.**

  - **Pro:** Now the module can be used in casts without throwing an error.
  - **Contra:** I must import modules only for casting. That feels wrong. It's suboptimal, and sometimes it causes circular imports.
- **Ignore the type-checker's error with a `# type: ignore` comment**

  - **Pro:** I don't need to cast.
  - **Contra:** Silencing the type checker on a line-by-line basis is a last-resort solution. I prefer something cleaner.

Do you know how to tell the type-checker `mypy` - other than a cast or assertion - that `foo_obj.get_something()` *will* return a `Bar()`-object in this situation? Or is there a way to do a cast without crashing the code at runtime (because of a missing module)?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. I'm getting an error that `something` is not defined. Also, `Foo.__init__` is unnecessary, and you haven't specified `Bar`, though I assume `class Bar: pass` will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can pass type names to any of the `typing` functions as strings. `mypy` will be smart enough to do the resolution, and the Python runtime won't complain since it's just a string. So you can do the cast like this.

```
bar_obj = cast('bar.Bar', foo_obj.get_something())
```